# Plotting in Mathematica - only getting empty axes

Tags: plotting

I am quite new to Mathematica and I cannot find what I'm looking for on the Stackexchange or on the Mathematica help pages.

I have the following function
$$U=\int^\tau_0 \bar{u}e^{-\rho t}dt \,+ \int^\infty_\tau ve^{-\rho t}dt$$
I am trying to form a plot that shows how the value of $U$ changes as $\tau$ changes, where everything else is constant. I would like to plot from $\tau=[0,2]$.

I have set $\bar{u} = 0.5$, $\rho=1$, $v=1$ for $t>0.5$ and $v=0$ otherwise.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
u=0.5
v=\[Piecewise]  0   t<0.5   1   t>0.5
ρ=1
Plot[Integrate[u E^(-ρ t), {t, 0, τ}]+Integrate[v E^(-ρ t), {t, τ, infinity}], {τ, 0, 2}]
```

When I run this, I only get an empty set of axes from 0 to 2. I have also tried defining the function "U", and then plotting "U", but I get the same result.

How do I form a plot for $U$ against $\tau$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not getting a plot usually means that there are symbols in the expressions describing the plot that cannot be resolved.

There are two issues here. 1.) I corrected the `Piecewise` in the definition of `v`. 2.) I changed `infinity` to `Infinity`. For speeding up the computation, I changed also `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`.

```
u = 0.5
v = Piecewise[{{0 , t < 0.5}, {1, t > 0.5}}]
ρ = 1
Plot[NIntegrate[u E^(-ρ t), {t, 0, τ}] + 
  NIntegrate[v E^(-ρ t), {t, τ, Infinity}], {τ, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Another possibility is to compute the integrand once symbolically (this is one of the rare instance where this is possible) and plot the result:

```
integrand = Integrate[u E^(-ρ t), {t, 0, τ}] + 
   Integrate[v E^(-ρ t), {t, τ, Infinity}, Assumptions -> τ > 0];
Plot[integrand, {τ, 0, 2}]
```

Note also that I had to help `Integrate` to find the integral by adding the option `Assumptions -> τ > 0`.